# Python glob: sorting files of format [int]_[int] the same as windows name sort

Tags: python, sorting, glob

I have files that are sorted by name in windows like the following:

```
1_0
1_1
1_2
1_3
1_4
1_5
1_6
1_7
1_8
1_9
1_10
1_11
2_0
2_1
```

Per above the first integer before the `_` should be the first sort, followed by the integer after the `_`. I want to sort in glob the same way. However, when I use `sorted(glob.glob(files))` I get an order like the following instead:

```
1_1
1_10
1_11
1_12
1_13
1_14
1_15
1_16
1_17
1_18
1_19
1_2
```

For files of the above format, is there a simple way to make glob sort by name the same way as windows does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give multiple keys to the sorting function in order of relevance

```
sorted(glob.glob(files), key=lambda x: (int(x.split('_')[0]), int(x.split('_')[1])))
```

> ['1_0', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5', '1_6', '1_7', '1_8', '1_9', '1_10', '1_11', '2_0', '2_1']